# How do I access list inside an object

Tags: c#, list, oop

How can I read the values inside H_N1_N2,H_N1_N3,H_N1_N4 that calls from H_N1_N1.

My objective is to put all the values into List that contains another object inside.

The requirement is to eliminate the current process which is storing the values to temp table in database before validation. After validated, it goes to the physical table.

Here's my entities:

```
public class H_N1_N1
{
    public string N101_EntityIdentifierCode { get; set; }
    public string N102_Name { get; set; }
    public string N103_IdentificationCodeQualifier { get; set; }
    public string N104_IdentificationCode { get; set; }

    public H_N1_N1()
    {
        ListH_N1_N2 = new List<H_N1_N2>();
        ListH_N1_N3 = new List<H_N1_N3>();
        ListH_N1_N4 = new List<H_N1_N4>();
    }

    public List<H_N1_N2> ListH_N1_N2 { get; set; }
    public List<H_N1_N3> ListH_N1_N3 { get; set; }
    public List<H_N1_N4> ListH_N1_N4 { get; set; }
}

public class H_N1_N2
{
    public string N201_Name01 { get; set; }
    public string N202_Name02 { get; set; }
}

public class H_N1_N3
{
    public string N301_AddressInformation01 { get; set; }
    public string N302_AddressInformation02 { get; set; }
}

public class H_N1_N4
{
    public string N401_CityName { get; set; }
    public string N402_StateProvinceCode { get; set; }
    public string N403_PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string N404_CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I populate my object:

```
var N1_N1 = dal.GetModelDetails(11);
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(N1_N1.MaxLoop); i++)
{
    H_N1_N1 oH_N1_N1 = new H_N1_N1();
    stElements = ResizeArray(stElements.Count(), stElements, "H_N1_N1");
    oH_N1_N1.N101_EntityIdentifierCode = stElements[1];
    oH_N1_N1.N102_Name = stElements[2];
    oH_N1_N1.N103_IdentificationCodeQualifier = stElements[3];
    oH_N1_N1.N104_IdentificationCode = stElements[4];
    objH_N1_N1.Add(oH_N1_N1);

    var N1_N2 = dal.GetModelDetails(12);
    H_N1_N2 oH_N1_N2 = new H_N1_N2();
    stElements = ResizeArray(stElements.Count(), stElements, "H_N1_N2");
    oH_N1_N2.N201_Name01 = stElements[1];
    oH_N1_N2.N202_Name02 = stElements[2];
    oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2.Add(oH_N1_N2);

    var N1_N3 = dal.GetModelDetails(14);
    H_N1_N3 oH_N1_N3 = new H_N1_N3();
    stElements = ResizeArray(stElements.Count(), stElements, "H_N1_N3");
    oH_N1_N3.N301_AddressInformation01 = stElements[1];
    oH_N1_N3.N302_AddressInformation02 = stElements[2];
    oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N3.Add(oH_N1_N3);

    var N1_N4 = dal.GetModelDetails(16);
    H_N1_N4 oH_N1_N4 = new H_N1_N4();
    stElements = ResizeArray(stElements.Count(), stElements, "H_N1_N4");
    oH_N1_N4.N401_CityName = stElements[1];
    oH_N1_N4.N402_StateProvinceCode = stElements[2];
    oH_N1_N4.N403_PostalCode = stElements[3];
    oH_N1_N4.N404_CountryCode = stElements[4];
}
```

There's the part where I cannot read the object:

```
foreach (var oH_N1_N1 in objH_N1_N1)
{   
    MessageBox.Show(
        // Print N1
        oH_N1_N1.N101_EntityIdentifierCode
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N102_Name
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N103_IdentificationCodeQualifier
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N104_IdentificationCode

        // Print N2
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2.N201_Name01 //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2.N201_Name02 //ERROR HERE

        // Print N3
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N3.N301_AddressInformation01 //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N3.N301_AddressInformation02 //ERROR HERE

        // Print N4
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N401_CityName //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N402_StateProvinceCode //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N403_PostalCode //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N404_CountryCode //ERROR HERE
    );
}
```

This is what i am trying to do:
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N2_somedata
N2_somedata
N3_somedata
N3_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata

N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N2_somedata
N2_somedata
N3_somedata
N3_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata

N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N1_somedata
N2_somedata
N2_somedata
N3_somedata
N3_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata
N4_somedata

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you give your variables proper names? They all look the same...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a troll question, but I certainly have no idea what the poster is trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, this code makes me want to weep for little children, but the reason you're getting errors is because you're placing 4 separate variables in `MessageBox.Show()` call and not tying them together.

**Update**

Based on your comment,

> when I try to type oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2, there is no N201_Name01 and N201_Name02

That's because `oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2` is a `List<H_N1_N2>` property. You cannot access properties of H_N1_N2 that way. You have to access via the list, for example using the indexer:

```
oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2[0].N201_Name01
```

You can also do `foreach` to get all of the elements...

```
string crazyNames = string.Empty;
foreach(var crazyName in oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2)
{
    crazyNames += crazyName.N201_Name01 + " " + N201_Name02 // etc.
}
```

Notice the `[0]` above which is the first element in the list. Now, the intellisense will show you available properties of the stored object, which is an instance of `H_N1_N2` and will contain the property `N201_Name01` and so on.

---

**Original issue / answer:**

Add + signs there and it'll work.

For the love of humanity please use some different naming conventions!

```
foreach (var oH_N1_N1 in objH_N1_N1)
{   
    MessageBox.Show(
        // Print N1
        oH_N1_N1.N101_EntityIdentifierCode
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N102_Name
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N103_IdentificationCodeQualifier
        + "\n" + oH_N1_N1.N104_IdentificationCode

            + // concatenate next object to first one 

        // Print N2
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2.N201_Name01 //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2.N201_Name02 //ERROR HERE

            + // concatenate next object to first+second one 

        // Print N3
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N3.N301_AddressInformation01 //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N3.N301_AddressInformation02 //ERROR HERE

            + // concatenate last object to first+second+third one 

        // Print N4
        oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N401_CityName //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N402_StateProvinceCode //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N403_PostalCode //ERROR HERE
        +"\n" + oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N4.N404_CountryCode //ERROR HERE
    );
}
```

Comment: I can't believe you strained your eyes to find that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: haha, it'll take some time to regain the lost brain cells, but hey that's what we sacrifice here on SO to help others!

Comment: hello guys, sorry for bad naming conventions.. but still.. when I try to type oH_N1_N1.ListH_N1_N2, there is no N201_Name01 and N201_Name02 in it even i set modifier to public in my entity layer.. any ideas?

Comment: @devkiat: see my updated answer based on your comment. Painful as it was, I addressed your concern.

Comment: I don't think anything can *truly* solve your problem until you get those names changed, hehe. But glad to help.

Comment: And I won't lie, I had to use my browser's "search" function to be able to read the code! :)

Comment: our naming convention is based on EDI segments

Comment: So there's a method to the madness. http://www.edi-services.com/commonly-used-edi-segments.htm